# "Add Client-Side Library" option is missing in Visual Studio 2019 Community

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, libman

I am trying to follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?tabs=visual-studio&view=aspnetcore-3.1) tutorial, which asks me to [Add Client-Side Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?tabs=visual-studio&view=aspnetcore-3.1#add-the-signalr-client-library), but I simply don't have that option available:

[image: option missing from Add menu].

VS version: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, Version 16.6.1

ASP.NET and web development workload is installed, I tried to install everything it would need, but still nothing.

All other Library Manager-related options are missing from the GUI.

Based on [LibraryManager's GitHub repository](https://github.com/aspnet/LibraryManager), it would not require install since it is *"Fully integrated into Visual Studio 2017 and newer"* but unfortunately it seems like not.

Comment: Hi Károly!  I have completed this same tutorial using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, Version 16.6.0 without issue.  I have had the problem you referred to when I created a Razor Class Library, not a Web Application.  In your web project, what is listed under Dependencies -> Framework?  You should see Microsoft.AspNetCore.App and Microsoft.NETCore.App.

Comment: did you find any solution for this...

Comment: I had the same problem when I used Console App when creating the project. If you make a Web app “Add Client-Side Library” option should be available.

Comment: Anybody have an answer for this? I am still seeing the issue in VS2019 Community Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.9.1  in an ASP.NET 5.0 in March 2021.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure the [Microsoft Library Manager](https://github.com/aspnet/LibraryManager) extension is installed/enabled.  Mine was disabled for some reason, I enabled it, restarted VS2019(16.10 Preview 1.0), and "Manage Client-Side Libraries..." was back in the menu.

[image: Enable Microsoft Library Manager extension]

Answer (score 1):

Check the Project SDK. The Option is only available for Web SDK Projects not for i.e. Razor Class Libraries.

So for Projects based on:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

-> Add Clientside Libraries is available

For Projects based on:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">
```

-> Add Clientside Libraries is **not** available

Change the Project SDK to your needs and the reload the Project.